# xcode 8 swift 3 latlong working on simulator but not in device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have this code to get location latlong

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class Utilities{

 static let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

 static func InitLocator(Delegate:CLLocationManagerDelegate){

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    locationManager.delegate = Delegate

    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone

    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


 }

 static func GetLatLong() -> [String]{


    var arrLatLong:[String] = []

    if let latitude = locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude{
        arrLatLong.append(String(latitude))
    }else{
        arrLatLong.append("")
    }

    if let longitude = locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude{
        arrLatLong.append(String(longitude))
    }else{
        arrLatLong.append("")
    }

    return arrLatLong

  }

 }
```

This works when I test or run it in the simulator but when I test it in an actual device it gives me blank values. I use Xcode 8 swift, the device is Iphone 6s IOS 9.3.1

Comment: which one give you bank value

Comment: latitude longitude

Comment: try with adding locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() and info.plist

Comment: That worked. Thanks.

Comment: could you help me to mark my Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

adding `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` and **info.plist**